# select data which occured on every three last month only and also which occured on the first and last three last month only according to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm analyzing sms data in my web application how do i select failed sms which occurred in last three  month on every month  and also the ones which occurred on the first month and on the third  month of the last three month  and also for the last two month  of the last three month

i can only select all failed sms for the last three month with this query

```
SELECT phone,
       Year(dte)                AS year,
       Month(dte)               AS month,
       Count(status = "failed") AS count_status
FROM   testdte
WHERE  dte BETWEEN Date(Now()) - INTERVAL(Day(Now())-1) day - INTERVAL 3 month
                   AND Now(
                   )
GROUP  BY Year(dte),
          Month(dte),
          phone
ORDER  BY Year(dte),
          Month(dte),
          phone
```

i expect to the output to be specific those failed sms last three month which occurred one every month and which occurred on the first and third month of the last three month and also the second and third of the last three month

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Are you only interested in aggregates or aggregates by phone?

Answer (score -1):

If -- for each `phone` -- you want to know how many failed in each of the past three months, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT phone, SUM(status = 'failed') as total_failed,
       SUM( status = 'failed' AND MONTH(dte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ) as failed_month_0,
       SUM( status = 'failed' AND MONTH(dte) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ) as failed_month_1,
       SUM( status = 'failed' AND MONTH(dte) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ) as failed_month_2,
       SUM( status = 'failed' AND MONTH(dte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) as failed_month_3
FROM testdte
WHERE dte >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL (1 - Day( CURDATE() )) DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND
      dte < CURDATE()
GROUP BY phone
ORDER BY phone;
```

Note that `COUNT( status = 'failed' )` **does not** count the failed statuses.  It counts any row where `status` is not `NULL`.  You want to use `SUM()` to get the count.